# Pdfreactor loses running footer

Tags: pdf-reactor

I am working with pdf-reactor and cannot make the header and footer to be in every page. I can, if I have only those two elements, header and footer, they are showing, but soon as I enter a single letter, footer disappears.

```
<div class="header">
    <table class="header header-footer">
        <tr>
            <td class="invoicetext">header</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <table class="footer header-footer">
        <tr>
            <td class="pagecounter">footer1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```
    @page {
        margin: 2cm 2.5cm 3cm 2.5cm;

        @top-left {
            content: element(headerIdentifier);
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }
        @bottom-left {
            content: element(footerIdentifier);
            vertical-align: top;
            width: 100%;
        }
        @bottom-right {
            content: element(companyIdentifier);
            vertical-align: top;
            margin-top: 4mm;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }


div.spacing {
    margin-top: 1.2em;
}

div.footer, div.header {
    font: 9pt arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}

div.footer {
    position: running(footerIdentifier);
}

div.header {
    position: running(headerIdentifier);
}
```

No matter where I add another div, on the top, bottom, between the header and footer, footer just disappears. How to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

We can reproduce this behavior here (issue #7827 in our internal tracking system). It seems to only occur when the running elements contain tables and when they are followed by only inline elements or text.

As a workaround, you could wrap the content after the running elements in a block element like this:

```
<div class="header">
    ...
</div>
<div class="footer">
    ...
</div>
<p>Some Text</p>
```

Comment: This issue is resolved since PDFreactor Version 10.1.10772.5.